# Hyperbolic space $H^n\subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ has constant curvature equal to -1

Tags: differential-forms

Show that in the hyperbolic space $H^n\subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ has constant curvature equal to -1.

**DOUBT:** How can I resolve this using only differential forms language?

PS: If $n=2$ then I would find a parametrization and apply $d\omega_{12}=-K\omega_1\wedge \omega_2$ after calculating coframe and connection forms. However with the power, $n$ is more difficult, and I couldn't think of a solution.

Comment: How are you getting $H^n$ sitting inside $\Bbb R^{n+1}$?

Comment: I do not know the answer. But I guess is an object in Riemannian Geometry. However, I am studying Differential Forms without this background.

Comment: You need to start with a hyperboloid in Lorentz space, not Euclidean $\Bbb R^{n+1}$. Perhaps [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1056136/curvature-of-de-sitters-space-where-does-the-sign-comes/1056693#1056693) will get you started.

Comment: Looks very interesting. Geometry is beautiful. 
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Have you made any progress with the question or answer?

Comment: By myself, I wasn't able. However I friend of mine helped me and we resolved. I didn't know that in this question I needed to define a metric. That was new for me. We achieved.